# Android Studio grid view overlapping?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gridview

I am trying to recreate the look below, however I am struggling to get the gridview to act correctly. For some reason the images are overlapping one another and I cant seem to create the appropiate padding between each tile. I have added the GridView code below.

[image: Desired Ui Look]

[image: Actual Output]

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/containerProfileGridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp">


</GridView>
```

Comment: @RasoolGhana That creates spacing below each row

Answer (score 0):

Please add `android:verticalSpacing` in GriwView which defines the default vertical spacing between rows. Have a look in Android Doc [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)